# Single website, single database schema multiple copies

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, concept

I know it maybe a mess in a logic I am thinking of, but the scenario is that I have a website which has 8 multiple copies same website same database schema but published on different places on the same server.

My problem is that I have about 50 stored procedures (per database), so  what can I do to make maintenance easier?

Every time I modify one stored procedure shall I modify it at 8 places? Shall I change the `web.config` file 8 times each publish operation?

I am thinking about making a simple CMS system which I will store publish directories and on button click it will publish all project to selected directories, but still I have a problem which is the stored procedures? On first publish I am thinking of altering the whole stored procedures at first publish.

Please any suggestion is welcome, now I have only one copy and you know its hard to maintain after taking the decision.

BTW the website is ASP.NET Web Forms but I can port it to any new .NET web technology like MVC or .NET Core.

Comment: "but the scenario is that I have a website which has 8 multiple copies same website same database schema but published on different places on the same server." - **why?**

Comment: "BTW the website is ASP.NET Web Forms but I can port it to any new .NET web technology like MVC or .NET Core." - uhm, how? **There is no easy way to port WebForms projects to ASP.NET MVC or .NET Core** - you'll need to rewrite all of your `.aspx` as `.cshtml` which is non-trivial if you're using Controls or Server-Side Events or anything like ASP.NET AJAX.

Comment: @Dai because each Website, Database belongs to a different company, so i need them separated

Comment: "so i need them separated" - have you considered using a multi-tenant database design instead?

Comment: I have not heard of that before, but would not databases share the data? so the main idea that I don't want the data to be transferred between databases

Comment: " but would not databases share the data?" - modern RDBMS have built-in support for data security and partitioning in multi-tenant scenarios, and even if they don't it's straightforward to bake tenant security in to your application's data access layer provided your application is architectured correctly.

Comment: For example, if you use Composite Primary Keys in your database (such that the `TenantId` is always included in a Composite key) and you have referential-integrity enabled (and if you don't then you should consider changing career...) then your DBMS will make it impossible for data to be referenced between tenants.

Comment: @Dai I really appreciate your answers ,I get your point

Answer (score 3):

If you have full control over the hosting then a "multi-tenant database design" as suggested by [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) would be a better approach. However if the circumstances require multiple instances then you can do the following:

1. Store a version number in your database so you know which scripts have run and which haven't.
2. Script any schema changes (which includes any Stored Procedures), potentially seed data, **and** including a new database version number.
3. Store the scripts in a directory under the website.
4. Have a maintenance routine (manual or automatic), which runs any new scripts which haven't been run before, by comparing the version numbers.